# I cant able to convert the base64 encoded string to hex string in android?

Tags: android, base64, aes

I am using `AES` (Rijndael) encryption method to encrypt a string. The transformation used is `ECB_PKCS5PADDING`. It will return a `base64` encoded string. I had decoded the string using `base64` and converted to `hex` using a function. The code snippets are attached below.

```
private void encrptString() 
 {
    sample = "<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String encrypt = Encoder.BuilderAES()
            .message(sample)
            .method(AES.Method.AES_ECB_PKCS5PADDING)
            .key("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .keySize(AES.Key.SIZE_128)
            .encrypt();

    System.out.println("encrypt"+encrypt);

    String stringFromBase = new String(Base64.decode(encrypt,Base64.DEFAULT));
    System.out.println("base64"+stringFromBase.trim());



   String hex= null;
   try {
       hex = toHex(stringFromBase);
   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   Toast.makeText(this, hex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   System.out.println("hex"+hex.trim());


   }

public String toHex(String arg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes("UTF-8")));


}
```

**base64 Input String:**

> O3Kmyftikp0lY/8SVWMiLFCn9sdQX7HauqdLZXcE+jkVcZH7kfPD/
>   jSLIC2wlP1iQTaiynoaW8A7L1INEYunkmCWT2eVwumwouHVT7d5Kq
>   /sqEcB9/9pyyAuSjrQxtCgJlHm7dlvt0lVEHD2pHnEAhZTRtuuy6b 
>   8MNI7W4jLn+/ZNEqZxdJll26a52D7ceFv

**Expected output:**

> 3b72a6c9fb62929d2563ff125563222c50a7f6c7505fb1dabaa74b657704fa391571
>   91fb91f3c3fe348b202db094fd624136a2ca7a1a5bc03b2f520d118ba79260964f67
>   95c2e9b0a2e1d54fb7792aafeca84701f7ff69cb202e4a3ad0c6d0a02651e6edd96fb
>   749551070f6a479c402165346dbaecba6fc30d23b5b88cb9fe
>   fd9344a99c5d265976e9ae760fb71e16f

**I am getting this output:**

> 3b72efbfbdefbfbdefbfbd62efbfbdefbfbd2563efbfbd125563222c50efbfbdefbfbd
>   efbfbd505fefbfbddabaefbfbd4b657704efbfbd391571efbfbdefbfbdefbfbdefbfbd
>   efbfbd34efbfbd202defbfbdefbfbdefbfbd624136efbfbdefbfbd7a1a5befbfbd3b2f
>   520d11efbfbdefbfbdefbfbd60efbfbd4f67efbfbdefbfbde9b0a2efbfbdefbfbd4fef
>   bfbd792aefbfbdefbfbd4701efbfbdefbfbd69efbfbd202e4a3aefbfbdefbfbdd0a026
>   51efbfbdefbfbdefbfbd6fefbfbd49551070efbfbd79efbfbd02165346dbaecba6efbf
>   bd30efbfbd3b5befbfbdcb9fefbfbdefbfbd344aefbfbdefbfbdefbfbd65efbfbd6eef
>   bfbdefbfbd60efbfbd

Answer (score 1):

I'd leave the decoded Base64 as a `byte[]` and encode that:

```
    String b64 = "O3Kmyftikp0lY/8SVWMiLFCn9sdQX7HauqdLZXcE+jkVcZH7kfPD/ jSLIC2wlP1iQTaiynoaW8A7L1INEYunkmCWT2eVwumwouHVT7d5Kq /sqEcB9/9pyyAuSjrQxtCgJlHm7dlvt0lVEHD2pHnEAhZTRtuuy6b 8MNI7W4jLn+/ZNEqZxdJll26a52D7ceFv";

    StringBuilder hexStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : Base64.decode(b64, Base64.DEFAULT)) {
        hexStringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }

    String hex = hexStringBuilder.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should base64-decode to a byte array (`byte[]`) and then hex encode the byte array to a string.